# GWT and JScience

Tags: gwt, jscience

In my GWT application, I made a control to display/edit a numerical value with an associated unit (for example to convert meters <-> feet).

How could I use the JScience library (jsr-275 implementation) in the client part ?

I try to add it to my project but it didn't compile:

```
No source code is available for type java.text.ParsePosition
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with the JScience library as such.

GWT compiles java to javascript and as such needs access to the java *source* code. Also, not all of the JDK classes are available in the GWT emulation library, and `ParsePosition` (indeed all of `java.text.*`) is one of them...

It is not clear from your stacktrace excerpt whether you have used `ParsePosition` directly or it is the JScience library that does, but either way you will have to rewrite your code to not use that class on the client side (if possible) or perform the conversion on the server side, where the GWT JRE restrictions do not apply.

Have a look at [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/RefJreEmulation) for a complete overview of what's available to you.

Cheers and good luck,

Comment: Well in fact my code is not using this class, it's in the code of JScience library (in javax.measure.Unit)...

Comment: I use: `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("convert")
    public interface ConvertService extends RemoteService {    
        Double convertKgToPound(Measurable<Mass> weight);
    }`, and Mass use Unit class, which uses javax.text...